# Do static functions in Swift cause memory leaks?

Tags: swift

Do static functions cause a memory leak when a closure is passed as an argument?

I have the following scenario where I create a `Section` via a struct called `SectionBuilder` and call its `static` function. I pass a function as a parameter to that function. Would this approach cause a memory leak?

```swift
class MyClass {
  var section: Section?

  func createSections() {
    section = SectionBuilder.make(didSelectHandler: didSelectHandler)    
  }

  func didSelectHandler() {
    let controller = DestinationController()
    view?.push(controller: controller)
  }
}
```

```swift
struct SectionBuilder {
  static func make(didSelectHandler: (() -> Void)?) -> Section {
    return Section(didSelectHandler: didSelectHandler)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about static functions that would cause memory leaks. That said, you are creating an object (A `Section`) and passing it a closure. If the `Section` retains the closure then the closure is an "escaping" closure. Closures themselves can have strong references to variables from their enclosing scopes, so escaping closures can be a source of memory leaks.

Here's one way your code could cause a memory leak: You hav a `Foo` object that call `SectionBuilder`'s make() function, and passes in a closure. That closure refers to an instance variable of the `Foo` object. Your `Foo` object then keeps a reference to the `Section` object that's passed to it. Now the `Foo` object has a strong reference to the `Section` object. The `Section` object has a strong reference to the closure, and the closure has a strong reference to the `Foo` object.